# Zoom in for details javafx pane with thousands shapes

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have javafx pane containing about 50000 of shapes. When I cache pane with `CacheHint.Speed` it is fine for Zooming and Panning. But it is so blurry when zoom. If set to `CacheHint.Quality` it becomes so sluggish. 
I am trying the solution of playing with `CacheHint` but unable to catch `OnScrollFinished` event on desktop. Clipping the pane doesn't help. 
I am thinking of selecting viewed shapes to render instead of rendering all shapes but what is the efficient way for checking about 50000 shapes?

Could some please help me with some options.

Thank you

Comment: [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)?

Comment: Could you say a little bit more about the nature of your shapes? Are they complex or are they simple? What shape primitives do you use? Do they move or not. Do you use effects or not? There are a lot of optimizations possible in JavaFX but their usefulness depends a lot on the exact scenario.

Comment: @mipa, There are basicly three kinds of objects in my pane: SVGPath, image, text. a path can be complex or very simple. Every path is attached to the mouse event listener to tell when It is pressed. They are not moved.

Comment: There are no effect too.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to analyze which of your primitive types has the major effect on performance and then start optimizing that.

Paths are notoriously slow in JavaFX (compared to Lines and Rectangles for example).

- Replace SVGPaths which just represent simple Lines and Rectangles by
  the JavaFX counter parts if you can.
- Simplify the paths if you can.
- Remove all geometries from the scene graph which are currently not visible.
- Use a triangle mesh to display your geometries. If done right this gives you a real performance boost but it is a lot of work (I've done it :-)

Using lots of tiny images may also be very slow. If that is the bottleneck it might help to create a texture atlas from your images and use a triangle mesh to display them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no experience with triangle mesh. How could I apply for my case? It is basicly 2D drawings with a lot of discontinuous and separated paths, no relations between them? they are simply separated lines like 2D drawings or maps.

Comment: The idea is to convert every shape into a triangle mesh and then let JavaFX render that. This is very fast because it is really done in hardware. The conversion though is a lot of work because there are no ready libraries available for that in Java/JavaFX. I found some good stuff in the JavaScript world made for WebGL and converted some code to Java for use in JavaFX. But I have not yet finished that and there are still a lot of open issues.

Comment: This is overwhelmed to me but as your comments it is worthwhile to try. Lets say I can convert shape to mesh then where in JavaFx can I load this the mesh to?

Comment: The classes to look for are: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/MeshView.html But as I said already this is a lot of work and before you follow this road you should make sure that all other optimizations are not enough.

Comment: Yes, I will take it as a side strategy. I am wondering whether I can listen to mouse event anymore?. Thank you so much!